# How to create a job in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I know that execute a command and add `&` to the end would create a job and make the command execute in background.

Now I want to create a job in a bash shell. I tried

```
#!/bin/bash

my-job &
# some other tasks
```

Then I executed `jobs`, but I got no output. However, `ps aux` does show `my-job` is running in the background.

I want to create a job inside a script, because in some cases I want to bring the job into foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jobs` are usually an interactive shell concept, as there is usually a controlling terminal involved.

A shell script is executed in a non-interactive, non-login session of shell, hence no job control by default.

You can force job control inside a script, by setting:

```
set -m
```

inside the script.

From `help set`:

```
-m  Job control is enabled.
```